# Undefined type in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Sorry, I have a weird question; I know undefined is a type in JavaScript; is it possible to set the type of a variable to undefined?

This is a serious question for me although it seems weird.

Comment: why not just do it?    var a=undefined;

Comment: Variables don't have types in Javascript, values do.

Comment: You can do `variable = undefined`.

Comment: @Barmar, so a variable whose type is undefined doesn't have any value, does it?

Comment: When you try to access a variable that isn't defined, you get the value `undefined`. The type of that value is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in several ways:
Just declare a symbol:

`var symbol;`

Or declare a symbol and set it to  undefined:

`var symbol = undefined;`

In case the undefined symbol was overridden:

`var symbol = void 0;`

Or

`var symbol = (function(arg) { return arg; })();`

Comment: Thanks for copy my answer

Answer (score 0):

Accoding MDN documentation:

> The global undefined property represents the primitive value undefined. It is one of JavaScript's primitive types.
> Property attributes of undefined
>
> Writable   **NO**
>
> Enumerable **NO**
>
> Configurable   **NO**

Ways to declare an undefined variable:

```
var foo;
var bar = undefined;
var baz = void 0;
var undefined = 2; // <= NO

console.log(foo); //undefined
console.log(bar); //undefined
console.log(baz); //undefined
console.log(undefined); //undefined
```

Mysteriously. Before you could declare the value to undefined, but now I try, and you can not. I guess now it is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

Say your variable is named `test`:

```
delete test; // true
typeof(test); // "undefined"
```

This may not work with the strictest of linters or JavaScript runtime environments. This only works if the variable is in the global scope.